# How would I convert a raster image such as a PBM to a CSV file?

Tags: r, csv, raster

I am trying to convert a raster image in the file type of PBM to a CSV file.

I have tried this:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/")
directory <- "test.pbm"
ndirectory <- "test.csv"

file_name <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".pbm")

files.to.read <- paste(directory, file_name) 
files.to.write <- paste(ndirectory, paste(sub(".pbm","", 
file_name),".csv"))

for (i in 1:length(files.to.read)) {
  temp <- (read.csv(files.to.read[i], header = TRUE, skip = 11, 
  fill = TRUE))
  write.csv(temp, file = files.to.write[i])
}
```

But I am getting the error "No such file or directory" but the file is definitely inside my Desktop directory. Am I overcomplicating this or does anyone have any suggestions how I could move forward?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the src files absolute paths by setting the path and full.names flag. 
And then replace the ".pbm" to ".csv" to get the destination file names easily.

Try this.

```
src_files <- list.files(path="~/Desktop/",pattern = ".pbm", full.names = TRUE)
dest_files <- sub(".pbm", ".csv", src_files)
for (i in 1:length(src_files)) {
  temp <- (read.csv(src_files[i], header = TRUE, skip = 11, fill = TRUE))
  write.csv(temp, file = dest_files[i])
}
```

Comment: Hi @abhilb! Thanks for contributing! Do you put the name of the pbm file you wish to convert to csv inside the path for src_files? I have tried this and I get the "No such file or directory" error still. Also getting the error "object 'True' not found".

Comment: what is the output of ```print(src_files) ```

Comment: oops.. sorry I had set the pattern to .json earlier.. I have corrected the code now. check it out.

Comment: When I print src_files I get the following error: Error in list.files(path = "~/Desktop/", pattern = ".pbm", full.names = True) : 
object 'True' not found

Comment: my bad it has to be full.names=TRUE. updated the code again.

Comment: Ok thanks but I'm still getting the error that there's no such file or directory:

Comment: `directory <- "test.pbm"
 ndirectory <- "test.csv"

 file_name <- list.files(directory, pattern = ".pbm")

 files.to.read <- paste(directory, file_name) 
 files.to.write <- paste(ndirectory, paste(sub(".pbm","", file_name),".csv"))

 src_files <- list.files(path="~/Desktop/",pattern = ".pbm", full.names = TRUE)
 dest_files <- sub(".pbm", ".csv", src_files)
 for (i in 1:length(files.to.read)) {
   temp <- (read.csv(files.to.read[i], header = TRUE, skip = 11, 
                    fill = TRUE))
   write.csv(temp, file = files.to.write[i])
 }`

Comment: i made so many copy paste errors. Check now.. it should work now hopefully..

Comment: at the beginning i only intended to show you how to get the src and dest file names and didn't pay attention to the rest of the code.

Comment: another question is it possible to convert pbm files to csv files like this?